# Loading my code on the Web Archive and JavaScript not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make my code function well through multiple viewings, such as the [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org) and through [PHProxy](https://px.multiscreensite.com). Here is the code :

```
<select id="mySelect" OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
</select>

<script>
    if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "http://th") {
        var home_var = "/";
        var bio_var = "/tagged/bio";
        var ask_var = "/ask";
    } else if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "https://p") {
        var home_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com";
        var bio_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com/tagged/bio";
        var ask_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com/ask";
    } else if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "https://w") {
        var home_var = "blog.tumblr.com";
        var bio_var = "blog.tumblr.com/tagged/bio";
        var ask_var = "blog.tumblr.com/ask";
    }
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");

    option.text = "Home Page";
    option.value = home_var;
    select.add(option);

    option1.text = "Autobiographys";
    option1.value = bio_var;
    select.add(option1);

    option2.text = "Ask Me Stuff";
    option2.value = ask_var;
    select.add(option2);
</script>
```

My specific problem is when opening my page through the Web Archive the variables never properly get defined so all of the values come out as "undefined". Is this a problem with the Web Archive, or is there anyway I can get around the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href.substring(0,9)` does not contain the matched string.
The condition was not mached and the default value also not defined because of this reason the value come out as undefined.

check with

```
console.log(window.location.href.substring(0, 9));
```

this is what i've tried

```
<select id="mySelect" OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
</select>

<script>
    var home_var = "";
    var bio_var = "";
    var ask_var = "";
    // Check your variable
    console.log(window.location.href.substring(0, 9));
    if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "http://th") {
        home_var = "/";
        bio_var = "/tagged/bio";
        ask_var = "/ask";
    } else if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "https://p") {
        home_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com";
        bio_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com/tagged/bio";
        ask_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=blog.tumblr.com/ask";
    } else if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "https://w") {
        home_var = "blog.tumblr.com";
        bio_var = "blog.tumblr.com/tagged/bio";
        ask_var = "blog.tumblr.com/ask";
    } else {
        //Set Default Values
        home_var = "default home var";
        bio_var = "default home var";
        ask_var = "default home var";
    }
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");

    option.text = "Home Page";
    option.value = home_var;
    select.add(option);

    option1.text = "Autobiographys";
    option1.value = bio_var;
    select.add(option1);

    option2.text = "Ask Me Stuff";
    option2.value = ask_var;
    select.add(option2);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.